# Accessing an element in a Set

Tags: java

How can I access a specific element in a `Set`?
For example, in a `Vector` I can access an element using  `vector.elementAt(i)`, but it doesn't work for a `Set`.

Comment: There is no elements order in ```Set``` structure. Therefore, you cannot get it like in ```Vector```.

Comment: You can try to use ordered set implementation like ```TreeSet```, but I recommend you to consider changing structure for that task to some natively ordered, like ```List```.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.htm